# Auto substract both values from 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created two input fields where they should substract from each other keeping a max value at 100.

Currently it substracted value is shown in the second value. I want it to be interchangeable. Irrespective of whether I put in first or second input field, the answer shows in the other.

Could someone help?

```js
function updateDue() {
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalval").value);
    var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inideposit").value);
    // to make sure that they are numbers
    if (!total) { total = 0; }
    if (!val2) { val2 = 0; }
    var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
    ansD.value = total - val2;
    var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("inideposit").value);
    // to make sure that they are numbers
    if (!total) { total = 0; }
    if (!val1) { val1 = 0; }
    var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
    ansD.value = total - val1;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="totalval" name="totalval" value="100" onchange="updateDue()">
<div>
  Enter Value:
  <input type="text" name="inideposit" class="form-control" id="inideposit" onchange="updateDue()">
</div>
<div>
  Substracted:
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="remainingval" onchange="updateDue()">
</div>
```

Comment: Either separate into two functions, or be sensitive to the target of the event - you need to _read_ the _changed_ input, and _update_ the _other_. It is not possible to have a single unconditional workflow do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way to achieve this would be to group the inputs by class and attach a single event handler to them. Then you can take the entered value from `100`, and set the result to the field which was not interacted with by the user. To do that in jQuery is trivial:

```js
$('.updatedue').on('input', function() {  
  var total = parseInt($('#totalval').val(), 10) || 0;
  var subtracted = total - (parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0);
  $('.updatedue').not(this).val(subtracted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="totalval" name="totalval" value="100" />
<div>
  Enter Value:
  <input type="text" name="inideposit" class="updatedue form-control" id="inideposit" />
</div>
<div>
  Subtracted:
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="updatedue form-control" id="remainingval" />
</div>
```

You can easily validate this so that outputs `< 0` and `> 100` can be discounted, if required.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code as below

```js
function updateDue(box) {

    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById("totalval").value);
    if(box == 1){
        var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("inideposit").value);
        // to make sure that they are numbers
        if (!total) { total = 0; }
        if (!val) { val = 0; }
        var ansD = document.getElementById("remainingval");
        ansD.value = total - val;
    }else if(box == 2){
        var val = parseInt(document.getElementById("remainingval").value);
        // to make sure that they are numbers
        if (!total) { total = 0; }
        if (!val) { val = 0; }
        var ansD = document.getElementById("inideposit");
        ansD.value = total - val;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="totalval" name="totalval" value="100" onchange="updateDue(0)">
<div>
  Enter Value:
  <input type="text" name="inideposit" class="form-control" id="inideposit" onchange="updateDue(1)">
</div>
<div>
  Substracted:
  <input type="text" name="remainingval" class="form-control" id="remainingval" onchange="updateDue(2)">
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.